# Pretty print a julia set

Tags: printing, julia, set

Is there a quick function without looping etc to pretty print the items in a set without the "Set(Any[])" in Julia? Have searched to no avail.

I'm printing the output to use for a latex table and want the output Set(Any["a","b","c"]) to just read a,b,c.

Comment: `join(s|>collect|>sort,',')` will give the string "a,b,c"

Comment: Please add as an answer so I can accept - this is exactly what I needed, so simple!

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the string is:

```
join(s|>collect|>sort,',')
```

If the order of the elements can be more chaotic then `join(s,',')` is enough and more performant.